# abline doesn't plot my regression line

Tags: r, plot

newbie question. I have a simple dataset called beta. I've attached it so r can find it. I can scatterplot the 2 variables with plot(). But when I use abline() to plot a regression, I don't get a line. No error, just no line. My code below; very grateful for any help.

```
head(beta)
        Date   SandP   AAPL
1 2015-12-14 2043.41 110.49
2 2015-12-07 2012.37 113.18
3 2015-11-30 2091.69 119.03
4 2015-11-23 2090.11 117.81
5 2015-11-16 2089.17 119.30
6 2015-11-09 2023.04 112.34
plot(SandP,AAPL)
abline (lm(SandP~AAPL))
```

Comment: You plot Sand on x and AAPL on y, while your regression model has Sand on y and AAPL on x. And do yourself a favour, don't get in the habit of attaching your data. It clutters your environment, and can lead to issues later (for instance with sorting and subsetting).

Comment: Heroka, thanks a million. I really appreciate the help. That solved the problem. And I will take your advice about attaching. It's true that it has caused me "masking" problems already. Thanks again.